# Yeoman - webapp with grunt-php, how to configure gruntfile.js?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I have been using the yeoman webapp generator. And I think it's great!
Now I want to persuade the company where I work to use it, too. Only they work with php files.

So now I am trying to get **[grunt-php](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-php)**  working with **yo webapp** generator. 
But after spending lots of hours adjusting `gruntfile.js`, I give up.

Does anyone know how to get the webapp generator working with the yeoman webapp generator?